# Saving csv file from a web page using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do a test in Jmeter in which I want to download a csv file into my computer. I have read online that people put the path of the download file in Jmeter and the listener "save responses to file". However, the button that downloads the file does not lead to a link, it only puts the table that is being displayed on the web to a csv file.

I've tried to put the listener but I only get JSON and HTML responses saved to my computer, when I want the csv. Do you know what to do in these cases?

Here is the image of the page that I am trying to test 
Image [of the web](https://ibb.co/tLLCmWN)

And here is the link that I get recording downloading the file:
Image [of Scenario](https://ibb.co/6RBnYmc)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if it is the correct request which triggers the download using fiddler.
2. Check if the required correlation for the request is done. Ex viewstate,eventvalidation etc...Use fiddler
   I think the steps you followed are correct..either wrong request or coorelation is causing this.
   Kindly check.